# Enviar valores checkbox escolhidos por e-mail

Tags: php

Boa tarde.

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário porem os valores escolhidos no meu checkbox não chegam no email, já que os demais chegam. Como posso fazer meu formulario ler os checkbox e mandar a informação para meu e-mail ?

Segue o código.

```html
<form action="agenda-planejamentorh2.php" method="post">
  <h2>+IFORMAÇOES TREINAMENTO PLANEJAMENTO DE BUDGET DE RH</h2>
  <div class="row cf">
    <p>Seu Nome:</p>
    <input class="text-input" type="text" name="name" id="name"> </div>
  <div class="row cf">
    <p>Seu E-mail:</p>
    <input class="text-input" type="text" name="email" id="email"> </div>
  <div class="row cf">
    <p>Seu Cargo:</p>
    <input class="text-input" type="text" name="cargo" id="cargo"> </div>
  <div class="row cf">
    <p>Seu Telefone/WhatsApp:</p>
    <input class="text-input" type="text" name="phone" id="phone"> </div>
  <div class="row cf">
    <p>Turmas:</p>
    <div class="three col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="turma[]" id="turma1" value="Turma 1">
      <label class="checkbox-label" for="turma1"><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span class="text">1 - Turma <br>25/02 a 26/02</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="three col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="turma[]" id="turma2" value="Turma 2">
      <label class="checkbox-label" for="turma2"><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span class="text">2 - Turma <br>25/02 a 26/02</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row cf">
    <div class="message">Sua Mensagem</div>
    <textarea name="mensagem" id="t1"></textarea>
  </div>
  <row class="cf">
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar"> </row>
</form>
```

E segue o código php

```html
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$address = "guilherme.mendes@corpbusiness.com.br;";
$data = date("d/m/y"); //pega a data
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //pega o ip de quem enviou
$hora =  date("d/m/y - H:i:s"); //pega a hora
if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$error = false;
$fields = array( 'name', 'email', 'cargo', 'phone');

foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
 if ( empty($_POST[$field]) || trim($_POST[$field]) == '' )
  $error = true;
}

if ( !$error ) {

 $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
 $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $phone= stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
    $cargo= stripslashes($_POST['cargo']); 
    $turma= stripslashes($_POST['turma']);
    $mensagem= stripslashes($_POST['mensagem']);
 
 
 $e_subject = 'DOWNLOAD AGENDA TREINAMENTO -  Como Planejar o Orçamento de RH ';

 //CONTEUDO EMAIL

 $e_body = "\r\nDOWNLOAD AGENDA TREINAMENTO - Como Planejar o Orçamento de RH : $name" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
 $e_reply = "\r\nE-mail: $email" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_phone = "\r\nTelefone/Whats: $phone" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
 $e_cargo = "\r\nCargo: $cargo" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL; 
    $e_turma = "\r\nTurmas: $turma" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_mensagem = "\r\nMensagem: $mensagem" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_hora = "\r\nData: $hora" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_ip = "\r\nIp Usuario: $ip" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL; 


 $msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_reply .$e_cargo . $e_phone . $e_turma. $e_mensagem. $e_hora . $e_ip , 70 );

 $headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
 $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

 if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

  // EMAIL ENVIADO COM SUCESSO RESPOSTA.

  echo "<script>alert('Obrigado pelo DOWNLOAD da Agenda.');</script><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=http://ebscorp.corpbusiness.com.br/'>";

 } else {

  echo 'ERRO!';

 }

}

?>
```

Comment: Para separar os valores você pode usar `implode`, assim: implode(",",$_POST['turma']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$turma = stripslashes($_POST["turma"]); //Isso retorna um array


$turma = stripslashes($_POST["turma"][0]); //isso retorna o valor da primeira checkbox se ela estiver marcada
```

Então mude seu código para:

```
$turma = "";
$turma .= stripslashes($_POST["turma"][0]);
if($_POST["turma"][1] != "" && $_POST['turma'][0] != "")
    $turma .= " e ";
$turma .= stripslashes($_POST['turma'][1]);
```

Comment: Cara funcionou certinho, muito obrigado. Tanto escolhendo a primeira turma quanto a segunda, VLW